# How can i print numbers as barcode format and some strings with barcode printer

Tags: python, printing, barcode

I'm trying to print string and barcode with barcode printer. I can print strings with win32api but i need to set positions of items. And another issue is i can't convert barcode numbers to barcode format. My printer's label 4inches*4inches. Can anyone help me ?

```
self.cursor.execute(
            "INSERT INTO depo_film (barkod, film_turu, film_eni, firma_adi, kilo, tarih) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)",
            (barkod, film_turu, film_eni, firma_adi, kilo, tarih))
        self.connection.commit()

        with open("etiket_bilgileri.txt", "w") as file:
            file.write(f"Barkod: {barkod}\n")
            file.write(f"Film Türü: {film_turu}\n")
            file.write(f"Film Eni: {film_eni}\n")
            file.write(f"Firma Adı: {firma_adi}\n")
            file.write(f"Kilo: {kilo}\n")
            file.write(f"Tarih: {tarih}\n")
        filename="etiket_bilgileri.txt"
        win32api.ShellExecute(
            0,
            "printto",
            filename,
            '"%s"' % win32print.GetDefaultPrinter(),
            ".",
            0
        )
```

it was just a try but it is full of errors.

Comment: Have you tried [this package](https://pypi.org/project/python-barcode/)? I don't know anything about it, but I find it odd that you're asking how to make a barcode in Python without even mentioning whether you've tried the Python package designed to do that.

Comment: Since you mention "Barcode Printer", do you mean a physical device to print onto labels - such as those made by Zebra, SATO etc ?   In this case, you should probably study ZPL format. It may seem intimidating, but it's actually fairly simple.